# wamp- php_http.dll is not installed correctly

Tags: php, dll

I have got up the error `Fatal error:Class 'HttpRequest' not  found in C:\wamp\www\...`

So in order to enable http extension for php I have downloaded (From http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/snaps/)and copied following dlls into php/php5.5.12/ext.

```
extension=php_propro.dll
extension=php_raphf.dll
extension=php_http.dll
```

Wamp started with out error and http is enabled in php extensions.But still I am getting the same fatal error.

I have checked php info page(http://localhost/?phpinfo=1) and http section is not showing `Registered classes`

Did I do wrong installation over php_http.dll?

Please share your thoughts.

**Info:**
Wamp server : 2.5

Php version: 5.5.12

Compiler :MSVC11 (Visual C++ 2012)

Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12

Thread safety:enabled.

Downloaded php_http.dll version is php_http-2.0.0-5.5-ts-vc11-x64

Comment: Rather than a snap try from here http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/http/2.5.0/

Comment: @RiggsFolly,Tried from above link.When starting wamp prompt error `php_http.dl could not be loaded`

Comment: You did download the Thread Safe Version right? `-ts-vc11` and also the x86 or x64 that match your WAMPServer install right

Comment: Ya the same only..